# How to sort alphanumeric columns in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I'm trying to get this order:

```
ID
Q1                  
Q2              
Q3              
Q4
Q10
```

But I'm getting this order with `dplyr::arrange`:

```
Q1  
Q10             
Q2              
Q3              
Q4
```

Reproducible Example:

```
df <- tribble(~ID, 
        "Q1",
        "Q2",
        "Q3",
        "Q4",
        "Q10")
```

```
df %>% 
  arrange(ID)
```

Comment: since you have `tidyverse`, use `str_sort(x, numeric = TRUE)`

Comment: The provided answers below (and the linked potential duplicate) doesn't address the situation where there is more than one column (which is implicitly the question here as I understand it). In such case a possible solution is to convert the ID column into a factor: `df |> mutate(ID = factor(ID, str_sort(unique(ID), numeric = TRUE))) |> arrange(ID)`. In other words, I believe the question should be reopened.

Comment: I agree, but I wasn't surprised that the question was closed knowing how stack overflow works.

Comment: The `str_sort` option doesn't seem to work in the dataframe on it's own. Perhaps it needs to be part of another approach to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, `dplyr`/base only. This relies on the assumption that there is only one such "number" within each value, and it is not interrupted. (For instance, `"A1B2C"` will sort here as `12`.)

```r
dat %>%
  arrange(suppressWarnings(as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", ID))))
#    ID
# 1  Q1
# 2  Q2
# 3  Q3
# 4  Q4
# 5 Q10
```

If you prefer to only use the first (if multiple) number, then we can use `readr::parse_number`:

```r
dat %>%
  arrange(suppressWarnings(readr::parse_number(ID)))
#    ID
# 1  Q1
# 2  Q2
# 3  Q3
# 4  Q4
# 5 Q10
```

I continue to `suppressWarnings` because any field with no numbers will be noisy, as in

```r
readr::parse_number("Q")
# Warning: 1 parsing failure.
# row col expected actual
#   1  -- a number      Q
# [1] NA
# attr(,"problems")
# # A tibble: 1 x 4
#     row   col expected actual
#   <int> <int> <chr>    <chr> 
# 1     1    NA a number Q
```

For the sake of this example, we don't care about the `"problems"` attribute attached to the output, and having it as `NA` is acceptable.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(ID = c("Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q10", "Q1")), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: doest the function `str_sort(x, numeric =TRUE)` solve the issue?

Comment: No, it returns `c("Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q10", "Q1")`

Comment: It clearly gives `"Q1"  "Q2"  "Q3"  "Q4"  "Q10"` as the result and not what you just stated

Comment: `str_sort(dat)` (wrong) returns `[1] "c(\"Q2\", \"Q3\", \"Q4\", \"Q10\", \"Q1\")"`. `str_sort(dat$ID)` returns `c("Q1", "Q10", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")`. What do you think I'm doing wrong? Note that the original question had strings already ordered, my `dat` does not (in order to demonstrate sorting it).

Comment: `str_sort(dat$ID, numeric = TRUE)` is what I wrote

Comment: Yes, I am using the unordered. or simply include sample. ie `str_sort(sample(dat$ID), numeric = TRUE)` it will always return the correct order

Comment: `stringr::str_sort(dat$ID, numeric=TRUE)` does return `c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q10")`, but `arrange(dat, stringr::str_sort(ID, numeric=TRUE))$ID` returns `c("Q2", "Q1", "Q3", "Q4", "Q10")` and `arrange(dat, stringr::str_order(ID, numeric=TRUE))$ID` returns `c("Q3", "Q4", "Q10", "Q1", "Q2")`. However, `slice(dat, stringr::str_order(ID, numeric=TRUE))` works.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution, based on `gtools::mixedsort`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(ID = gtools::mixedsort(ID))

#> # A tibble: 5 × 1
#>   ID   
#>   <chr>
#> 1 Q1   
#> 2 Q2   
#> 3 Q3   
#> 4 Q4   
#> 5 Q10
```

---

Or without using other library beyond `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", ID)))

#> # A tibble: 5 × 1
#>   ID   
#>   <chr>
#> 1 Q1   
#> 2 Q2   
#> 3 Q3   
#> 4 Q4   
#> 5 Q10
```

Comment: I like this answer, but Is there something without using another library?

Comment: Please, see my updated answer, @writer_typer.